# In Django, do I need syncdb after I added a method to a model?

Tags: python, django, model

I have added a new function to my model. This function doesn't need new data in the database/needs no schema changes.

Do I need syncdb in this case?

I suppose, I do not, but I don't see the new function in the runtime. If I do `dir(myModelsObject)` I just don't see this function.

What do I miss?

Thank you!

**Update:**

How do I check it?

```
wordlists = WordList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
for w in wordlists:
    print dir(w)
    print w.length()
```

`dir` does not show me the new method, though it shows me all of the old ones.

After that I have this exception:

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'WordList' object has no attribute 'length'
```

**Update 2:***

My model definition (partially):

```
class WordList(models.Model):
    list_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, default=_createId)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    ...

    def length(self):
        return len( self.load_words() )
```

Comment: You do not, but you might (e.g. if you're not running the development server) need to restart the server.

Comment: @thebjorn: I did it, but it had no effect

Comment: You don't need to run syncdb. What are you passing the `dir()`? Model class or model instance?

Comment: What is the traceback when you try to use your new function?

Comment: @IgorChubin could you show your model definition?

Comment: Did you mean to have `def length` outside of `class WordList`?

Comment: @univerio: Oh sorry, of course inside (that was a typo here, on SO)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me...

```
(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>cat maint\models.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class WordList(models.Model):
    list_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, default='42')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    #...

    def length(self):
        return len([])
```

calling syncdb because I didn't have the model in the db..

```
(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>python manage.py syncdb
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
...
 > datakortet.maint
...

(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>cat tstwordlist.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from maint.models import WordList

usr = User.objects.get(pk=1)
#WordList.objects.create(list_id=42, title='foo', user=usr)

wordlists = WordList.objects.filter(user=usr)
for w in wordlists:
    print dir(w)
    print w.length()


(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>python tstwordlist.py
['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', u'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_default_manager', '_deferred', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'full_clean', 'length', 'list_id', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'title', 'unique_error_message', 'user', 'user_id', 'validate_unique']
0
```

adding a length2

```
(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>cat maint\models.py
...    
class WordList(models.Model):
    #...

    def length(self):
        return len([])

    def length2(self):
        return len([42])
```

don't do a syncdb, but change the program to use length2 (and only print the keys in `dir()` that start with length)..

```
(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>cat tstwordlist.py
...
wordlists = WordList.objects.filter(user=usr)
for w in wordlists:
    print [name for name in dir(w) if name.startswith('length')]
    print w.length2()
```

works as expected...

```
(dev) C:\work\dev\datakortet>python tstwordlist.py
['length', 'length2']
1
```

Comment: I've updated the answer (adding another property, not calling syncdb, still works for me).  Could you have a circular import?

Comment: That's really strange, I have no idea why it does not work. Anyway, thank you very much for the help, +1

Comment: If you provide the entire traceback we could potentially provide some more help...